# Manga about 3 school friends who have to play games to survive

Tags: imawa-no-kuni-no-alice

I am having a tough time trying to remember the name of this manga. It had three high school friends and they woke up in an alternate reality where people play games to survive. The games difficulty is determined by a something and can determine the difficulty by a deck of cards.

The first game was something like 2 of diamonds and they had to get fortune cookies and survive a bunch of flaming arrows (Which they did). One of the group guys is smart while the other of the group guys is really brave then they have a 3rd member who is worthless it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Imawa no Kuni no Alice**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=59540) (English title: **Alice in Borderland**) is most likely what you are looking for. It is adapted into an OVA series, which has 3 episodes at the time of writing.

> Alice Ryouhei will leave high school soon, but he's trying to avoid thinking about his future. Late one night, when he's hanging out with his tough friend Karube and his silly, girl-crazy friend Chota, they see fireworks. After one blindingly bright explosion, they find themselves waking up in a different world. In this 'Borderland,' people are forced to either participate in potentially deadly games or simply die. Will Chota, Karube, and Ryouhei be able to survive this dangerous new world, and is there a way they can get back to their original lives?

Here is a page from chapter 2 showing their first game, in which whoever answers the small problem on the [*omikuji*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-mikuji) incorrectly will be shot as many flame arrows as the difference between the wrong and right answer. Normally, *omikuji* is a piece of paper with fortune written on it, but in this story, it contains a problem plus some hint to clear the game.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind expanding on that answer? E.g, state similar plot points that matches the OP's request?

Comment: I just read the first few chapters and yes this is what I was looking for. Thank you very much~!

Answer (score -2):

If it was recent (as in the last couple of years), then it could be [Problem Children Are Coming From Another World, Aren't They?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_Children_Are_Coming_from_Another_World,_Aren't_They%3F). The plot synopsis on Wikipedia reads:

> Three children, Sakamaki Izayoi, Kudō Asuka, and Kasukabe Yō, live dull lives because they possess unmatched psychic powers. One day, they receive an envelope that transports them to Little Garden, a place of supernatural powers called "Gifts." There, the residents use Gifts to play high-stakes games known as Gift Games in order to earn wealth and prestige for their communities. So, the three children join the fallen "No Name" community and resolve to help it regain its prosperity. As they learn more about Little Garden, they decide to overthrow the tyrannical Demon Lords in control.

Comment: There's nothing about using a deck of cards in the games in "Problem Children...".

Comment: That's true. I haven't watched the show, so I was basing it off a bit where the Wikipedia article mentions that the first game they play in this world is a card game.